# XML Deserialize multiple elements same class with different behavior

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework, serialization, deserialization

I hope my questions was not asked before because i searched for a while now.

Here's the thing, I have some xml serialization and once deserialized it become an entity which can be added to my database with EF 4.0.

Actually everything work with this element :

```
<MyObject Attribute1="" Attribute2="" Attribute3="" />
```

I would like another object like this :

```
<MyObjectBefore Attribute1="" Attibute3="" />
```

This Element shoul be deserialized like `MyObject` class and a default value to Attribute2.

Is it possible ?
Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0):

If you have a constructor or field initialiser that assigns the default value, it will already work. XmlSerializer doesn't support serialisation callbacks, and missing values do not cause default assignments - so the only other option would be to implement IXmlSerializable (which is frankly: really painful).